# how to enable swipe carousel event for extjs5

Tags: touch, swipe, extjs5

```
Ext.define('SApp.view.appCrd.InCarousel', {
     extend: 'Ext.view.View',
     xtype: 'InCarousel',
     id:'InCarouselContent',

    requires: ['Ext.data.Store',
            'SApp.model.appCrd.InDetailModel',
            'SApp.model.appCrd.InMeasureModel',
            ],
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="item thumb-wrap">',
                '<div class="thumb" style="width:180px; height:180px;">',
                '<div ><span class="thumb-title-home-page {class}"><span>{InName}</span></span></div>',
                    '<tpl for="measureData">',
                        '<div class="thumb-description" ><span class="thumb-description-name">{key}</span>  <span class="thumb-description-value">{value}</span></div>',
                    '</tpl>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],

    itemSelector: 'div.thumb-wrap',
   multiSelect: true,
   listeners: {
        click: {
            element: 'el',
            fn: function(){var createappCrdInDetailView = new Ext.create('SApp.view.appCrd.appCrdInDetailView');
                var vport = Ext.getCmp('appCrdMainContent');
                vport.removeAll(true, true);
                vport.add(createappCrdInDetailView.show());}
        },
        dblclick: {
            element: 'body', 
            fn: function(){ console.log('dblclick body'); }
        }
   },
    singleSelect: true,
    cls: 'x-image-view',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'CustomerDataStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'SApp.model.appCrd.InDetailModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : '../SApp/resources/data/appCrd/InList.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            }
        });

        this.callParent();
    }
 });
```

Comment: How about explaining that code?  Code blocks on their own are not very informative. Please explain what the code you're showing does, why you chose to write it that way, and how you expect it to work.

Comment: code is working after changing listener

Answer (score 1):

code is working after changing listener

```
swipe: {
            element: 'el', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
            event: 'swipe',
            fn: function(event){ 
                if(event.direction == 'left'){
                    slideRight()
                }else{
                    slideLeft()

                }
            }
        }
```